# find $\int_C \left\vert z \right\vert dz$ where $C$ is the left half of a circle from $-i$ to $i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, line-integrals

The question is "find $$\int_C \left\vert z \right\vert dz$$ where $C$ is the left half of a circle from $-i$ to $i$". The expected answer is $2i$. I tried to solve the problem, but my answer is different:

$$
z(t)=ie^{it}
$$
(since the radius of the circle is $i$, and $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$)

Then:
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=-e^{it}$$

and
$$
f(z(t)) = \left\vert z(t) \right\vert = \left\vert ie^{it} \right\vert = \sqrt{(ie^{it})^2}
$$

$$
-\int \limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} e^{it}\cdot \sqrt{(ie^{it})^2}\,dt
$$

In order to solve the above integral, I used $u=ie^{it}$ and $-du=e^{it}dt$ and then the integral became:

$$
\int \limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \sqrt{u^2} \, du
$$
which is equal to (I think...)
$$
\frac{u^2}{2} = \frac{i^2e^{2it}}{2} = \frac{-e^{2it}}{2}
$$

And if I substitude $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$:
$$
\frac{-e^{2i(\frac{3\pi}{2})}}{2} - \frac{-e^{2i(\frac{\pi}{2})}}{2} = \frac{-1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = -1
$$

What is wrong about my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the radius of the circle is $r=|i|=1$.

Let $z=e^{it}$ and $dz = ie^{it}dt$. Then $|z|=|e^{it}|=1$

$$\int_C{|z|}\mathrm{dz}=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}ie^{it}dt=-i\frac{e^{it}}{i}|_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}=-e^{\frac{i3\pi}{2}}+e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}=-(-i)+i=2i$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Could you please clarify that why did you get $z(t)=e^{it}$ and not $ie^{it}$? As I know, The formula for parameterize a circle is $re^{it}$ where $r$ is the radius, and in this case, $r = i$.

Comment: @JavadKouhi What on earth is a circle with radius $i$?

Comment: @JavadKouhi: i added the explanation in my answer, why $r=1$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't noticed that. Now it's clear. Thank you both.